# OpenSSL Crypto development libraries are not installed properly in required location

Tags: linux, centos, c, turnkey

When I configure [turnserver-3.2.3.95](http://turnserver.open-sys.org/downloads/v3.2.3.95/) in my CentOS, I meet the following problem.

```bsh
$ cd turnserver-3.2.3.95/

$ sudo ./configure 
more is /bin/more
install is /bin/install
pkill is /bin/pkill
Use TMP dir /var/tmp
Compiler: cc
Do not use -lsocket
Do not use -lwldap32
Do not use -lwldap64
Do not use -lintl
Sockets code is fine: no sin_len field present
Ignore IP_RECVERR
Do not use -lcrypto
ERROR: OpenSSL Crypto development libraries are not installed properly in required location.
Abort.
```

I try to install some libraries by using the following command, but it doesn't work when I configure again.

```bsh
$ sudo yum install openssl openssl-libs libevent libevent-devel
```

This is version of my OS.

```bsh
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

What should I do to solve it?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1059499/error-openssl-crypto-development-libraries-are-not-installed-properly-in-requir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On CentOS (and other RPM-based distributions), you need to install the `openssl-devel` package:

```
sudo yum install openssl-devel
```

(Use `sudo dnf ...` on CentOS 8, RHEL 8 or Fedora.)

The equivalent in the Debian ecosystem is `libssl-dev`.